# Boto3 Parameter Validation error with list in json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am getting the following error from boto3 and I'm not sure what the best way to resolve the issue is.

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter parameters.headers, value: ['SALE_PRSN_KEY', 'SALE_PRSN_ID', 'SALE_PRSN_INIT'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter parameters.column_count, value: 14, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

I am passing the following json file:

```
{
    "models": [{
        "name": "sales_person_data",
        "headers": ["SALE_PRSN_KEY", "SALE_PRSN_ID", "SALE_PRSN_INIT"]
    }]
}
```

Then reading it as follows:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
result = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket',
                       Key='my_config.json')

models = json.loads(result["Body"].read().decode())
```

Is there a better way to pass in a list as a parameter?

Comment: Your JSON file is not valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it. Was taking a snippet of my code to synthesize the question

Comment: This works perfectly for me with boto3 v1.9.252 and Python v3.7.6. Does the metadata for the object show Content-Type=application/json?

Comment: How exactly do I got about getting the metadata for the object? Thanks!

Comment: Simplest way is S3 console, navigate to bucket and object, go to properties tab, see metadata card.

Comment: hmm, it says Content-Type=application/json like you said, but still only allows strings. I'm using this with airflow to dynamically process tasks by pulling specific values from the json file, so I'm not sure if there is some sort of type requirements with that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207905/discussion-between-jarmod-and-sanjayr).